# Getting NaN as a result from Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, nan

JS code

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

});

function calculatePPI(inputWidth, inputHeight, inputDiagonal) {
  document.getElementById("outputPPI").innerHTML= 
((Math.sqrt(Math.pow('inputWidth', 2)) + (Math.pow('inputHeight', 2)))/'inputDiagonal');
}
```

HTML code

```
<body>

    <h2>Length Converter</h2>
    <p>The following program will convert your centimeters to inches.</p>

    <p>
        <label>Width (Pixels):</label>
        <input id="inputWidth" type="number" placeholder="Width">
        <p>
            <label>Height (Pixels):</label>
            <input id="inputHeight" type="number" placeholder="Height">
        </p>

        <p>
            <label>Diagonal (Pixels):</label>
            <input id="inputDiagonal" type="number" placeholder="Diagonal Length">
        </p>

        <button onclick="calculatePPI(document.getElementById('inputWidth', 'inputHeight', 'inputDiagonal').value)">Calculate</button>
    </p>

    <p>PPI: <span id="outputPPI"></span></p>

</body>
```

I'm getting NaN as a result whenever I try to calculate it.

[image: For example]

Could anyone help me with this? I'm not sure where exactly the code is messing up, as I'm new to coding Javascript.

Comment: Your use of `getElementById` is incorrect

Comment: You can't get the value from 3 elements at once, i.e. `document.getElementById('inputWidth', 'inputHeight', 'inputDiagonal').value` doesn't work.  you need to call `getElementById` 3 separate times.

Comment: Instead of using a string: `Math.pow('inputWidth', 2)`, you need to use the actual variable name instead: `Math.pow(inputWidth, 2)`

Comment: also, in your function, you are accepting 3 variables, but you aren't using them.  i.e. `inputWidth` is a variable, `'inputWidth'` is not that variable, it is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `getElementById` like that and in your function don't put a `''` around your function variable.

Use like this:

```js
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

});

function calculatePPI(inputWidth, inputHeight, inputDiagonal) {

  document.getElementById("outputPPI").innerHTML= 
((Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inputWidth, 2)) + (Math.pow(inputHeight, 2)))/inputDiagonal);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>

<h2>Length Converter</h2>
<p>The following program will convert your centimeters to inches.</p>

<p>
  <label>Width (Pixels):</label>
  <input id="inputWidth" type="number" placeholder="Width">
  <p><label>Height (Pixels):</label>
  <input id="inputHeight" type="number" placeholder="Height"></p>
  <p><label>Diagonal (Pixels):</label>
  <input id="inputDiagonal" type="number" placeholder="Diagonal Length"></p>

  <button onclick="calculatePPI(document.getElementById('inputWidth').value, document.getElementById('inputHeight').value, document.getElementById('inputDiagonal').value)">Calculate</button>
</p>
<p>PPI: <span id="outputPPI"></span></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line `(Math.sqrt(Math.pow('inputWidth', 2)) + (Math.pow('inputHeight', 2)))/'inputDiagonal');` the result is NaN because your doing math with strings. Remove the ' (single quotes).

`(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inputWidth, 2)) + (Math.pow(inputHeight, 2)))/inputDiagonal);`

This should work, because now your accessing the actual value of the variables inputWidth, inputHeight, etc. Before you were just creating strings.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<h2>Length Converter</h2>
<p>The following program will convert your centimeters to inches.</p>

<p>
  <label>Width (Pixels):</label>
  <input id="inputWidth" type="number" placeholder="Width">
  <p><label>Height (Pixels):</label>
  <input id="inputHeight" type="number" placeholder="Height"></p>
  <p><label>Diagonal (Pixels):</label>
  <input id="inputDiagonal" type="number" placeholder="Diagonal Length"></p>
<p>
  <button onclick="calculatePPI();">Calculate</button>
</p>
<p>PPI: <span id="outputPPI"></span></p>
```

**Javascript**

```
'use strict';

$(document).ready(function() {

});
function calculatePPI() {
var inputWidth = document.getElementById('inputWidth').value;
var inputHeight = document.getElementById('inputHeight').value;
var inputDiagonal = document.getElementById('inputDiagonal').value;
var outputPPI = document.getElementById("outputPPI");
  outputPPI.innerHTML= ((Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inputWidth, 2)) + (Math.pow(inputHeight, 2)))/inputDiagonal);
}
```

Note: there lots of syntax error in code like the assignment of value in the calculation of PPI and in function value for the parameters.You can try above code your calculation with native javascript and below one for **JQuery**.

```
function calculatePPI() {
var inputWidth = $('#inputWidth').val();
var inputHeight = $('#inputHeight').val();
var inputDiagonal = $('#inputDiagonal').vval();
var outputPPI = $("#outputPPI");
  outputPPI.html(((Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inputWidth, 2)) + (Math.pow(inputHeight, 2)))/inputDiagonal));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript return `NaN` when you are not calculating with valid Numbers

> `NaN` = Not A Number

Make sure your operands are valid number in your equation.

You can try like -

```
<button onclick="calculatePPI('inputWidth','inputHeight','inputDiagonal')">Calculate</button>

function calculatePPI(inputWidth, inputHeight, inputDiagonal) {
   inputWidth    = document.getElementById(inputWidth).value
   inputHeight   = document.getElementById(inputHeight).value
   inputDiagonal = document.getElementById(inputDiagonal).value

   inputWidth    = inputWidth ?  inputWidth  : 0;      /*Setting default value 0*/
   inputHeight   = inputHeight ? inputHeight : 0;      /*Setting default value 0*/
   inputDiagonal = inputDiagonal ? inputDiagonal : 0;  /*Setting default value 0*/
   document.getElementById("outputPPI").innerHTML = ((Math.sqrt(Math.pow(inputWidth, 2)) + (Math.pow(inputHeight, 2)))/inputDiagonal);
}
```